# How to lock cell according to another cell value whitout VBA

Tags: excel

I'm using 2 excel columns.

I want to prevent the editon of the second one according to the value of the first one.

I have already tried that in the second cell : `IF(A1<>1000;B1.Locked = True;B1.Locked = False)`

But it is not working ... I can still edit the cell.

Moreover, the content of the second cell is managed by a data validation system which allow only 3 values (`Yes`, `No`, `Maybe`).

Is it possible to do that whitout VBA code?

Thank you for help.

Comment: No, this is only possible with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought this wasn't possible, as it's not at all possible to lock cells with a formula. But for your situation, it might actually be possible using data validation. Here is how:

Create a named range anywhere in your workbook containing the values "Yes", "No", "Maybe". In my case I've named this `YesNoList`.

Then in your cell, you [put on data validation](https://exceljet.net/sites/default/files/styles/function_screen/public/images/formulas/data%20validation%20with%20conditional%20list%20setup.png?itok=Mu9_gd-s) (similar to picture in link) allowing a list with the following formula. (assuming cell `AB1` is blank)

```
=IF(A1<>1000,YesNoList,AB1)
```

This will allow the cell to be filled with values from your `YesNoList` if the condition is met, and will not allow anything if not (since the validation list is blank assuming AB1 is blank, if not, put in any other blank cell)

You can of course have some fixed values in the cell you're referencing as well, if you don't want it to be blank. Perhaps you could put some more formulas in the last part to allow exactly what you need. Just make sure you reference a cell or range directly, or you will get an error.

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm getting this error : `#VALUE!` for `=IF(A1<>1000;"N/A";ComplexityList)`. But if `A1` value is different that `1000`, value in the cell is `N/A` so that's ok.

Comment: Can you check your ComplexityList holds the exact values you want in the validation dropdown? Also are you putting this formula in the data validation menu or a cell? It won't work in a cell, as it will then try to cram multiple values in a cell.

Comment: Yes I try to put the content of the list in one cell because I need a dropdown list with the 3 values.

Comment: You will need to put the formula into data validation, as this creates the dropdown list. You cannot get a dropdown list from a formula in a cell.